# Returning results from DBT back to Airflow

Tags: python, ssh, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow, dbt

I'm looking for a way to get few dates back as result from a DBT script to Airflow and then use those dates to run a loop for another DBT script for data load for those specific dates. Is there a way this can be achieved? Or else how can I write a DBT script which will act as a wrapper for the other DBT script to run for specific dates? The database I'm using is Snowflake for storing the daily data.

I'm not sure how to get the dates back from a DBT script.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you could write the dates into a DB , and then use values from the table to fire shell commands that would execute "dbt run" on your models. What you are basically looking for is persistence, which could be anything as long as Airflow has an operator for it.

You might be tempted to use Xcoms for passing values between tasks, but I would recommend that you don't use it, as those are persisted into Airflow metadata DB and would only slow down the Airflow performance, if the data volumes are high.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. What I'm concerned with is, how will I get the date values back to airflow from the DB if I'm using DBT ?? It's not allowed to establish direct connection from Airflow to Snowflake sadly. So getting the dates back has been troubling me since the past few days.

There is an existing DBT which works perfectly fine. I want to loop it for the multiple dates using the existing task in airflow. But I don't get how to get the dates back to airflow from snowflake .

Comment: Okay, so your DBT is allowed to connect to SF, but Airflow isn't. Please use any other form of storage(cloud storage) or, worst case use Xcoms .Point to be noted here is that your second task needs to somehow be able to collect the results from the first task. Please correct me if the understanding is not correct .